# Deciding the parameter value in a ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, mathematical-modeling, biology

I am working with a system that includes pharmacokinetic and pharmacodynamic elements. To model the antibiotic effect on bacteria I am using a commonly used Hill type function as,${(\phi_{max} - \phi _{min}){({A \over MIC})}^k}\over {{({A \over MIC})}^k-{\phi_{min} \over \phi_{max}}}$,
where,
$\phi_{max}$ – maximum bacteria growth rate in the absence of antibiotic which is only limited by resources, and so it i limited by the carrying capacity term as,  $\phi_{max}=r(1-{P \over k})$, where $k$ is the carrying capacity term and $r$ is the replication rate, and $P$ is the bacterial density that change over time.

$\phi_{min}$ – minimum bacterial growth rate at high concentrations of the antibiotic.

$MIC$-minimum inhibitory concentration of the antibiotic

$k$ - Hill coefficient.

$\phi_{min},k,MIC$ are all constant values.

$A$ is the antibiotic concentration which decays exponentially so that ${dA\over dt}=-dA$

So, my question is, in almost all the articles that I found, the value of $\phi_{min}$ was selected as a **negative** value. But it is defined as a bacterial growth rate. So, how can a growth rate be negative?

When this function was used in my model and the $\phi_{min}$ value was changed from, negative values to positive values, for negative values I get the desired behaviour (the pathogen get cleared). But, for some positive values, in Matlab I get a warning as,

```
Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest
value allowed (1.818989e-12) at time t
```

Could this be because, that it is possible to come up with a situation where, $\phi_{min}=\phi_{max}$ and ${({A \over MIC})}^k=1$, so that the above function reaches $0 \over 0$ case.

I believe this does not happen when $\phi_{min}$ is negative, does it?

In articles, they just chose low negative value for antibiotics that has high killing ability (e.g $\phi_{min}=-3$)and for lesser effective antibiotics $\phi_{min}=-0.01$.

I would like to know if there is mathematical reason for choosing $\phi_{min}$ to be negative? Is my reasoning on $0 \over 0$ case reasonable?

Comment: Since antibiotics kill bacteria, Shouldn't their population begin to decrease in presence of large concentrations? Hence, their "growth" is negative, as the population should be decreasing? Otherwise, the antibiotic isn't really doing what it is supposed to be doing, killing bacteria, or at least killing them at too slow a rate to remove them and their effect on the host. A positive $\phi_{min}$ Would just indicate a decrease in the growth of the population, not a shrinkage. I also think that error just means that you have a divergent integral ( at least with the methods used by matlab), but

Comment: I could be wrong about that. It's been awhile since I actually performed integrals in MATLAB. What are we solving for the derivative of, by the way? I don't see it explicitly stated in the eqns.

Comment: @Shinaolord So, the ODE system is similar to ${dP\over dt}=r(1-{P \over k})- {(\phi_{max} - \phi _{min}){({A \over MIC})}^k}\over {{({A \over MIC})}^k-{\phi_{min} \over \phi_{max}}}$ and ${dA\over dt}=-dA$. I didn't get what you meant as  "A positive ϕmin Would just indicate a decrease in the growth of the population, not a shrinkage." The case is for some positive values, the bacterial load would decline, but it is for some positive values of $\phi_{min}$ only that the Matlab warning comes up.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the matlab error. By that statement i meant that in the presence of the antibiotic, a positive $\phi_{min}$ would just mean that the bacteria are increasing in number more slowly, no? Or am i misunderstanding what is meant by $\phi_{min}$?